# jQuery Callback Start jQuery over

Tags: javascript, jquery

if someone can help me fix this script it would be greatly appreciated.

I would provide a fiddle but the fiddle behaves differently then inside the wordpress iframe but I believe I have most of the code figured out (please correct me if there is a better way to write this code).

I believe I need to start my jQuery script over after an error, right now I am able to get the script to show the email input box after the user clicks the button with an invalid entry but because of the library I am using I must start the script from the beginning and I'm not sure how to do that properly.

I tried using the initial function as a callback but I keep getting an error because I need the api information again and all the survey parameters.

Here is the portion of the code where I think the problem is, is it possible to add a callback to start the script over on error?

/** Part of Code I need help with **/

```
 if(data.submitSurveyResponse.success == 'false') {
            $('input[type=text]').hide();
            $('#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').hide();
            $('#cons_email').show().select();
            $('#NextStepForm').show();
          $('.survey-form').prepend('<div id="survey-errors">' + 
                                      '<div class="alert alert-danger">' + 
                                        'There was an error with your submission. Please try again.' + 
                                      '</div>' + 
                                    '</div>');
```

/** End of code snippet **/

/** Begin jQuery Script **/

```
 (function($) {
  /* init variables */
  luminateExtend({
    apiKey: 'Key', 
    path: {
      nonsecure: 'http://mywebsite.com', 
      secure: 'https://mywebsite.com'
    }

  });

 $(function() {
$('#NextStepForm').click( function(e) {
     if ($('input[type=email]').val().length > 0) {
         e.preventDefault();
        $('input[type=email]').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#NextStepForm').hide();
    $('input[type=text]').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hidden');
    $('#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').removeClass('hidden');

    }
});

    /* UI handlers for the Survey example */
    if($('.survey-form').length > 0) {
      $('.survey-form').submit(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).before('<div class="well survey-loading">' + 
                         'Processing...' + 
                       '</div>');
      });
    }

    /* handle the Survey form submission */
    /* if the Survey is submitted succesfully, display a thank you message */
    /* if there is an error, display it inline */
    window.submitSurveyCallback = {
      error: function(data) {
        $('#survey-errors').remove();
        $('.survey-form .form-group .alert').remove();

        $('.survey-form').prepend('<div id="survey-errors">' + 
                                      '<div class="alert alert-danger">' + 
                                        data.errorResponse.message + 
                                      '</div>' + 
                                    '</div>');

        $('.survey-loading').remove();
        $('.survey-form').show();
      }, 
      success: function(data) {
        $('#survey-errors').remove();
        $('.survey-form .form-group .survey-alert-wrap').remove();

        if(data.submitSurveyResponse.success == 'false') {
            $('input[type=text]').hide();
            $('#ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE').hide();
            $('#cons_email').show().select();
            $('#NextStepForm').show();
          $('.survey-form').prepend('<div id="survey-errors">' + 
                                      '<div class="alert alert-danger">' + 
                                        'There was an error with your submission. Please try again.' + 
                                      '</div>' + 
                                    '</div>');

          var surveyErrors = luminateExtend.utils.ensureArray(data.submitSurveyResponse.errors);
          $.each(surveyErrors, function() {
            if(this.errorField) {
              $('input[email="' + this.errorField + '"]').closest('.form-group')
                                                        .prepend('<div class="col-sm-12 survey-alert-wrap">' + 
                                                                    '<div class="alert alert-danger">' +
                                                                     this.errorMessage + 
                                                                   '</div>' + 
                                                                 '</div>');
            }
          });

          $('.survey-loading').remove();
          $('.survey-form').show();
        }
        else {
          $('.survey-loading').remove();
          $('.survey-form').before('<div class="alert alert-success">' + 
                                 '<p>Thanks for joining. You should receive your first issue of the e-newsletter shortly.</p>' + 
                                     '</div>');
        }
      }
    };
    /* bind any forms with the "luminateApi" class */
    luminateExtend.api.bind();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

/** End jQuery Script **/

/******* html below *******/

```
<div id="quickregbox" class="container-fluid">
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <form data-toggle="validator" class="form-inline luminateApi survey-form" action="#" method="POST" data-luminateapi='{"callback": "submitSurveyCallback", "requiresAuth": "true"}'><input name="method" type="hidden" value="submitSurvey" />
            <input id="method" name="method" type="hidden" value="submitSurvey" />
            <input name="cons_email_opt_in" type="hidden" value="true" />
            <span style="display: none;">
            <input id="denySubmit" name="denySubmit" type="text" />Please leave this field empty</span>

                <div class="form-group row center-block">

                    <div class="consemaildiv form-group has-feedback">
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label for="cons_email" class="sr-only"></label>
                        <input id="cons_email" class="form-control margin-bottom border-radius padding-right" placeholder="Email Address" name="cons_email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" type="email" data-error="Please enter a valid email address" required maxlength="255"/>
                        <!-- <div class="help-block with-errors helpBlockWidth"></div>  help-block -->
                        </div><!-- column -->
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <button id="NextStepForm" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">></button>
                    </div><!-- column -->
                    </div> <!-- form-group consemaildiv-->

                    <div class="form-group consnamediv">

                            <label for="cons_first_name" class="sr-only"></label>
                            <input id="cons_first_name" class="form-control margin-bottom margin-top hidden border-radius name-width" placeholder="First Name" name="cons_first_name" type="text" maxlength="50"/>
                            <label for="cons_last_name" class="sr-only"></label>
                            <input id="cons_last_name" class="lnameMarginTop form-control margin-bottom hidden border-radius name-width" placeholder="Last Name" name="cons_last_name" type="text" maxlength="50"/>
                            <button id="ACTION_SUBMIT_SURVEY_RESPONSE" class="btn btn-primary hidden" type="submit">></button>
                        </div> <!-- column consnamediv-->

                </div><!-- form-group -->

        </form> <!-- form end -->

</div> <!-- column -->
```

/** End html **/

Comment: You could benefit a lot from breaking up your code into several functions. It'll make it easier to understand, and you can reuse code. Make sure you understand closures, especially nested functions and how they affect variable scope: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures